# CORS ~ JQuery ~ XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, google-api

I am very tired with this Issue

I try to fetch Google contact first log in by client Id and client Secret value and scope value like

```
scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&response_type=code
```

and set also redirect URI.

at server side I have manage Headers like

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
```

and JQuery function is as under

```
function ok(){
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain:true,
        cache : true, 
        data    :   
                {
                    code : '<%=auth_code%>',client_id: '<%=client_id%>',
                    client_secret : '<%=client_secret%>',redirect_uri: '<%=redirect_uri%>',
                    max_results : <%=max_results%>,grant_type:'authorization_code'
                },  
        url     : 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        success : function(data){
                //alert("success "+data['access_token']);
                var accesstoken = data['access_token'];
                //alert(accesstoken);
                var url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=<%=max_results%>&oauth_token='+accesstoken;
                //alert(url);

                $.ajax({
                    url     : url,
                    dataType: "xml",
                    type: "GET",
                    success : function(data){
                            alert("success "+data);


                             $(data).find("entry").each(function(){

                                for(var i=0 ;i<$(this)[0].children.length;i++){
                                    if($(this)[0].children[i].nodeName == "gd:email")
                                        console.log($(this)[0].children[i].attributes[1].textContent);
                                }

                             });
                        },
                    error: function(jqXHR, exception, errorstr) {
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                        alert(errorstr);
                    }
                    });


            },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception, errorstr) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            alert(errorstr);
        }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Issue with client side multiple request.

above code execute multiple request in ajax using JQuery.

In contrast I have hit URL at server Side (Servlet).

now code like

```
$.ajax({
        type    : 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain:true,
        cache : true, 
        data    :   
                {
                    code : '<%=auth_code%>'
                },  
        url     : '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/GetAccessTokenServlet',
        success : function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception, errorstr) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            alert(errorstr);
        }
        });
```

and servlet "GetAccessTokenServlet" like

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String code = request.getParameter("code");
        String grant_type = "authorization_code";
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        String accessparameters = String.format("client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&redirect_uri=%s&max_results=%s&code=%s&grant_type=%s",
                URLEncoder.encode(client_id, charset),URLEncoder.encode(client_secret, charset),URLEncoder.encode(redirect_uri, charset),
                URLEncoder.encode(max_results, charset),URLEncoder.encode(code, charset),URLEncoder.encode(grant_type, charset));
        String resultStr = "";
        try{
            URL accesstoken_url = new URL("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
            HttpURLConnection accesstokenConnection = (HttpURLConnection) accesstoken_url.openConnection();
            //          treeConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            accesstokenConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            accesstokenConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
            accesstokenConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            try {
                accesstokenConnection.getOutputStream().write(accessparameters.getBytes(charset));
            }
            finally {
                accesstokenConnection.getOutputStream().close();
            }

            BufferedReader accesstokenReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(accesstokenConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while((line = accesstokenReader.readLine()) != null){
                resultStr+=line;
            }
            System.out.println(resultStr);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resultStr);
            String oauth_token = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("access_token"));

            URL contactURL = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token="+oauth_token);
            HttpURLConnection contactConnection = (HttpURLConnection) contactURL.openConnection();
            contactConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            contactConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            contactConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            contactConnection.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
            contactConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            contactConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            contactConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

            System.out.println("length: "+contactConnection.getContentLength());
            System.out.println("type: "+contactConnection.getContentType());
            BufferedReader contactReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contactConnection.getInputStream()));

            String contactLine;
            String contactStr = "";
            while ((contactLine = contactReader.readLine()) != null) {
                contactStr += contactLine;
                //System.out.println("contactLine: "+contactLine);
                if(contactLine.contains("gd:email")){
                    String[] gdEmail = contactLine.split(" ");

                    for(int i=0;i<gdEmail.length;i++){
                        if(gdEmail[i].startsWith("address")){
                            System.out.println(gdEmail[i].substring(gdEmail[i].indexOf("=")+1));
                        }

                    }
                }

            }




        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        response.getWriter().write(resultStr.toString());
    }
```

this code returns friends EMail addresses.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url ="https://accounts.google.com/oenter code here/oauth2/token";
$fields = array(
   "client_id"=>"XXXXXXXXXX-j4r6g3XXXXXXXXXXXXXlg6f9lmn.apps.googleusercontent.com", //static data
   "client_secret"=>"FYefMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXzI4P",                                              //static data           
   "refresh_token"=>"1/haH1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXjQn9zY2_1xLg",                     //static data
   "grant_type"=>"refresh_token"                                                            //static data
);

$ch = curl_init($url);

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute post
$lResponse_json = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);


$responseObj = json_decode($lResponse_json,true);
```

?>

// for creating refresh token please follow https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization
once creating refresh token use above code to get access token to use API again and again
// javascript does not support cross domain origin policy so you have to use curl for overcoming this problem